# What's the difference between returning AsyncEnumerable with EnumeratorCancellation or looping WithCancellation

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I have the following method that reads a csv document from a http stream

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Line> GetLines([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = GetResponse();

    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader);

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await csvReader.ReadAsync())
    {
        yield return csvReader.GetRecord<Line>();
    }
}
```

and a method elsewhere that uses the result

```
var documentAsyncEnumerable = graphClient.GetLines(cancellationToken);
await foreach (var document in documentAsyncEnumerable.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
{
    // Do something with document    
}
```

My question is shouldn I use the cancellation token in just one place? Should the cancellation token be acted upon before yielding the record or is the IAsyncEnumerable.WithCancellation() basically doing the same thing? What is the difference if any?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under the hood the cancellation token is passed to `GetAsyncEnumerator` method anyway, according to the [sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/IAsyncEnumerable.cs,40a1440c806710a7,references)

```cs
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public interface IAsyncEnumerable<out T>
    {
        IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    }

    public interface IAsyncEnumerator<out T> : IAsyncDisposable
    {
        ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync();
        T Current { get; }
    }
}
```

You should use `cancellationToken` only once, passing directly or use `WithCancellation`, these methods are doing the same. `WithCancellation` is extension method for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, accepting a `CancellationToken` as an argument (it uses the same pattern with `ConfigureAwait`). In case of `[EnumeratorCancellation]` the compiler generate code that will pass the token to `GetAsyncEnumerator` method

The reason of two different ways are described in [MSDN magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8#a-tour-through-async-enumerables)

> Why two different ways to do it? Passing the token directly to the
>   method is easier, but it doesn’t work when you’re handed an arbitrary
>   IAsyncEnumerable from some other source but still want to be able
>   to request cancellation of everything that composes it. In
>   corner-cases, it can also be advantageous to pass the token to
>   GetAsyncEnumerator, as doing so avoids “burning in” the token in the
>   case where the single enumerable will be enumerated multiple times: By
>   passing it to GetAsyncEnumerator, a different token can be passed each
>   time.

Answer (score 12):

> My question is shouldn I use the cancellation token in just one place?

Cancellation is cooperative, so in order to **be able to cancel**, you **had** to implement cancellation in the *producer* code `GetLines`, the one that provides the `IAsyncEnumerable<Line>`. So, producer is one place.

Now, imagine that the method that the code that does something with that data is named `ConsumeLines`, let's say it's a *consumer*. In your case it could be one codebase, but generally speaking, it could be another library, another repo, another codebase.

In that other codebase, there is no guarantee they have the *same* `CancellationToken`.

So, how can a consumer cancel?

Consumer needs to pass a `CancellationToken` to the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator`, but it's not directly exposed if you're using `await foreach` construct.

To solve this, `WithCancellation` extension method was added. It simply forwards the `CancellationToken` passed to it to the underlying `IAsyncEnumerable` by wrapping it in a [ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/229bc90dc82c28d0c1a259b07995628391eb86f9/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable.cs).

Depending on several conditions, this `CancellationToken` is linked to the one in the producer using [CreateLinkedTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1) so that **consumer can cancel using cooperative cancellation implemented in the producer so not only we can cancel consuming, but also, producing**.

> Should the cancellation token be acted upon before yielding the record or is the IAsyncEnumerable.WithCancellation() basically doing the same thing? What is the difference if any?

**Yes**, you should act upon your `CancellationToken` by using either [IsCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationToken_IsCancellationRequested) or [ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationToken_ThrowIfCancellationRequested) in your *producer* code. Cancellation is cooperative, if you don't implement it in *producer*, you won't be able to cancel *producing* the values of `IAsyncEnumerable`.

As to when exactly to cancel - before or after yielding - it totally up to you, the idea is to **avoid any unnecessary work**. In this spirit, you could also check for cancellation in the first line of your method, to avoid sending an unnecessary http request.

Remember that **cancelling the consuming of the values, is not necessarily the same thing as cancelling the producing of the values.**

Again, producer and consumer could be in different codebases, and could be using `CancellationTokens` from different `CancellationTokenSources`.

**To link those different** `CancellationTokens` **together you need to use the** `EnumeratorCancellation` **attribute**.

Please read a more in-depth explanation in my article [EnumeratorCancellation: CancellationToken parameter from the generated IAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator will be unconsumed](https://oleh-zheleznyak.blogspot.com/2020/07/enumeratorcancellation.html)